# Given a sequence of numbers report which have been repeated and how many times

Tags: c++

for example

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5

1 repeated 3 times,
3 repeated 1 time,
5 repeated 2 times
```

here's the code but it has some troubles

```
int i, k, m, number, number_prev, e;
cout << "Insert how many numbers: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "insert number";
cin >> number;
number_prev = number;
int num_rep[m]; //array of repeated numbers
int cant_rep[m]; // array of correspondent number of repetitions
e = 0;

for (i=1; i<m; i++) 
{
    cin >> number; 
    if (number == number_prev)
    {
        if (number == num_rep[e-1])
            cant_rep[e-1]++;
        else
        {
            num_rep[e] = number;
            cant_rep[e] = e + 1;
            e++;
        }
    }
    else
        e = 0;
    number_prev = number;
}

for (k = 0; k < e; k++)
    cout << "\nnumber " << num_rep[k] << " repeated " << cant_rep[k] << " times.\n";
```

Comment: please tell us what's the "trouble"

Comment: No variable-length arrays in C++. Use a `std::vector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn algorithms and data structures. This make your code simpler. just using associative container that saves pair

```
a number --> how many times it repeats
```

can simplify your program sufficiently

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> map;
    int v;
    while(std::cin >> v) {
        map[v]++;
    }
    for (auto it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); ++it) {
        if (it->second > 1) {
            std::cout << it->first << " repeats " << it->second - 1 << " times\n";
        }
    }
}
```

`std::map` is an associative container.

You can think about it as a `key-->value` storage with unique keys.

The example in real word is a dictionary:

There you have *word* and its *definition*. The word is a *key* and the *definition* is a value.

```
std::map<int,       int> map;
         ^^^        ^^^
          |           |
         key type    value type
```

You can refer to values using `[]` operator.

this works like usual array, except instead of *index* you use your *key*.

You can also examine *all* key-value *pairs*, storied in the map using *iterators*.

```
it = map.cbegin(); // refers to the first key-value pair in the map
++it; // moves to the next key-value pair
it != map.cend(); // checks, if we at the end of map, so examined all elements already
```

As, I pointed out, map saves key-value *pairs*.

And in Standard C++ library `struct std::pair` is used to express *pair*.

It has `first` and `second` members, that represents first and second values, storied in a pair.

In the case of map, `first` is a *key*, and `second` is a *value*.

Again, we are storing *a number* as a key and *how many times it repeats* in a value.

Then, we read user input and increase *value* for the given *key*.

After that, we just examine all elements stored in a map and print them.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks, the only problem is that I dont understand it, I've never used maps

Comment: @RihardMarius, I tried to explain in breaf. Hope this helps, however you should read some book for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num_rep[m]; //array of repeated numbers
int cant_rep[m]; // array of correspondent number of repetitions
```

Here, m is only known when running, array sizes must be known in compile time. use `std::vector` instead.

The code seems like a C-style C++ program:

1.You don't need to declare variables in the beginning of block. Declare them before use, it's  more readable.

2.Use the `STL` types like `std::vector` can save you a lot of trouble in programs like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. you say "Insert m numbers", but `for (i=1; i<m; i++)` will loop m-1 times, which might not is what you want.
2. as a supplement advice, you should do input check for the variables get from external world.like `cin >> m;`, for it can be zero or negative.

Comment: 1. there is a cin >> number previous to the for loop, so the total would be m numbers 2. thanks, but later i'll refine the code, first i want it to work right